# Modal in HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, modal-dialog

I have created a modal in my html table, if I click on 3 dot icon the modal pops up, but only works on the first record of the table. If I click the icon in the second record, the modal does not pop up. I can't figure out what's the problem. Here is my code:

```
if ($count > 0) {
                while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                    $id = $rows['id'];
                    $workbook_vin = $rows['workbook_vin'];
                    $date_work = $rows['date_work'];
                    $user_full_name = $rows['user_full_name'];
                    $km = $rows['km'];
                    $work_hour = $rows['work_hour'];
                    $problem = $rows['problem'];
                    $remark = $rows['remark'];
        ?>

                    <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
                         <div class="modal">
                            <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/add-invoice.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-invoice"></i></button></a>
                            <br><br><br>
                            <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/bill.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i></button></a>
                            <br><br><br>
                            <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/images.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-camera"></i></button></a>
                            <br><br><br>
                            <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/show-images.php?workbook_id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-image"></i></button></a>
                            <br><br>
                            <button id="close" class="danger-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $sn++; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $workbook_vin; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $date_work; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $user_full_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $km; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $work_hour; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $problem; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $remark; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/update-workbook.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="main-btn"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></a>
                            <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/delete-workbook.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="danger-btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></a>
                            <button id="open" class="add-btn" ><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

I will attach 2 images, just to see how It looks and what I mean.

[image: how the table looks like]

[image: how the modal looks like]

And this is my JS code:

```
var open = document.getElementById("open");
var modalc = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-container");
var close = document.getElementById("close");

open.onclick = function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modalc.classList.toggle("show");
 };

close.onclick = function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   modalc.classList.remove("show");
 };
```

Comment: add js. Probably you are using button id ("open") to refer modal.

Comment: I added my JS code too.

Comment: @EdvardSupica did one of the answers solve our question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue of same modal id for different records.Make the modal id dynamic

Replace-

```
<div class="modal-container" id="modal-container-{id}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to open modals of other rows due to all modal having same id="modal-container"

You can do something like this for creating different modals

```
<div class="modal-container" id="modal-container-<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Also have to mention the same modal-id for buttons as well the script for each modal / row.

**Another Option**

You can keep one modal and just change the data while triggering

[Multiple Modals in single page](https://codepen.io/haydmills/pen/zLraGJ)

Comment: The button should have no id or a unique id as well. Nice suggestion to reduce code by only having one modal. :)

Answer (score 1):

EXayers comment and both answers are a part of solving your question.

Firstly you need to ensure that an `id` is unique for the modal container

```
<div class="modal-container" id="modal-container-<?= $id; ?>">
```

and the 3-dot-Button.

```
<button id="open-<?= $id; ?>" class="add-btn" ><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></button>
```

Now you have to rewrite your JS code to add (at least) an open Event Listener to all Open Buttons.

For close, you could either do the same or walk through all modals and remove the class when a close button is clicked.
Or you try in your close button

```
 <button id="close-<?= $id; ?>" class="danger-btn" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('modal-container-<?= $id?>')[0].classList.remove('show')">
```

---

If you are down for rewriting more code, you could consider [Arslaan Shaikh's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73362068/5841606) of having just one modal and adding some content to it, as far as I see only the id is changing in the links.

It would make your code more readable and fewer DOM elements are created.

P.S.: the opening of the modal could be done by inline JS as well. Depending on your preference.

Comment: How to to this : Now you have to rewrite your JS code to add (at least) an open Event Listener to all Open Buttons. ?

Comment: I assume you don't need help anymore, as you selected the other answer as the solution and went with this approach?